# Convert MongoDBObject to JsValue

Tags: mongodb, scala, playframework, casbah

Let's say I have ....

```
val obj: MongoDBObject = getDbObj
println(obj)
```

prints out:

`{ "_id" : "1234", "name":"Kevin", "age":"100" }`

How can I convert `obj` to a `JsValue`?

Comment: Are you asking about Play framework JsValue?  If so you should add a play framework tag.

Comment: Thanks, David. I just added. I appreciate your on-going help (from previous posts I've noticed your name and avatar).

Comment: you are hitting a lot of the same stuff I was running into about a month ago

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you do it for Play 2.1 ([documentation](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/ScalaJson))

```
val dbo = MongoDBObject("id" -> "0001", "name" -> "Kevin", "age" -> "100") 
val json: JsValue = Json.parse(dbo.toString)
```