# Adding JsValue to Mongo

Tags: mongodb, scala, casbah

Let's say I have a `JsValue`.

```
val dbo = MongoDBObject("id" -> "0001", "name" -> "Kevin", "age" -> "100") 
val json: JsValue = Json.parse(dbo.toString)
```

I tried to insert `json` [via](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18747315/convert-mongodbobject-to-jsvalue):

```
val obj = MongoDBObject("key" -> json)
collection.insert(obj)
```

However, there are many brackets `[` and `]` added to the `json` part when I do a `db.collection.findOne()` from the Mongo shell.

How can I properly add a JsValue into Mongo in Casbah?

Comment: Is it just the string representation of the jsValue thats being saved?

Comment: Yes. But I was able to save it by setting (in my example above) `json` equal to `com.mongodb.util.JSON.parse(Json.stringify(json)))`

Comment: Answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18881316/ covers this scenario.